# DocuSign SOAP API Update (Correct) Envelope Expiration

Tags: vb.net, soap, docusignapi

I'm using vb.net (4.0) to interact with the DocuSign API. I'm trying to make a process that allows a user to add 30 days to the current expiration date instead of logging into DocuSign.net to correct the envelope. The code seems to work fine (doesn't throw any errors) but the correction doesn't happen on DocuSign's side.

Me.EnvelopeID is the Envelope's ID

DocuService is the namespace of the DocuSign API Service Reference.

Me.AuthorizationString is the Username, Password, Account# and Integrator Key to send as HTTP headers.

```
    Private Sub UpdateExpiration()
    'Get envelope details
    Dim orig As DocuService.Envelope = ExecuteSoap(Function(client) client.RequestEnvelope(Me.EnvelopeID, False), Me.AuthorizationString)

    Dim cor As New DocuService.Correction
    cor.EnvelopeID = Me.EnvelopeID
    cor.Reminders = orig.Notification.Reminders
    cor.Expirations = orig.Notification.Expirations
    cor.Expirations.ExpireAfter = (Integer.Parse(orig.Notification.Expirations.ExpireAfter) + 30)


    'Execute Correction
    Dim cord As DocuService.CorrectionStatus = Me.ExecuteSoap(Function(client) client.CorrectAndResendEnvelope(cor), Me.AuthorizationString)
    'If I add a break point on the next line and check the values of cord,
    'there is a returned CorrectionStatus object but every property in the object is "Nothing"

    Dim check As DocuService.Envelope = ExecuteSoap(Function(client) client.RequestEnvelope(Me.EnvelopeID, False), Me.AuthorizationString)
    Console.WriteLine(check.Notification.Expirations.ExpireAfter & " " & (Integer.Parse(orig.Notification.Expirations.ExpireAfter) + 30))
    If check.Notification.Expirations.ExpireAfter = (Integer.Parse(orig.Notification.Expirations.ExpireAfter)) Then
        'Success :)
        MsgBox("success!")
    Else
        'Failure :(
        MsgBox("failure!")
    End If
    End Sub


Private Function ExecuteSoap(Of TResult)(func As Func(Of DSAPIServiceSoapClient, TResult), authorizationString As String) As TResult
    Using client As New DocuService.DSAPIServiceSoapClient(My.Settings.DocusignMode)
        Using scope As OperationContextScope = New System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel)
            Dim hp As HttpRequestMessageProperty = New HttpRequestMessageProperty
            hp.Headers.Add("X-Docusign-Authentication", authorizationString) 
          OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name) = hp
            Return If(func IsNot Nothing, func(client), Nothing)
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

We use the same ExecuteSOAP function and AuthorizationString to create & send envelops, and do recipient updates so I know these are correct. I'm not sure whats wrong!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely 1 of 3 possibilities.

- I'm surprised its not error-ing out, but you should not be putting your accountId in the http auth header.  See page 19 the SOAP PDF guide:
  http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSignAPI_Guide.pdf
- There is something else not configured correctly with your SOAP API call.  Inspect your raw outgoing request and ensure the xml is what you expect.  Post the raw request here if not sure.
- A bug with DocuSign.  First rule out the other two options and if no dice still post a comment here and I can get a bug logged on DocuSign's side.  Also a good test would be to make the correction call through the REST api to see if you can get that to work.

Comment: Thanks, I got put on another project for a week or two but I'll get back to this soon.